# Implementing memoir class in LyX

Tags: lyx, memoir, front-matter

I'm starting to learn the memoir class to use it with a book I'm writing in LyX.I've read most of the memman docuement. When I create a new LyX document I can enter the title, but not a subtitle, half-title page, or the other front matter pages.

Do I need to put all this in the LyX preamble?

TIA,

Rich

Comment: I know nothing about LyX. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I set the document class as 'memoir' then looked in the environments for front matter such as sub-title, half-title page, back-title-page, and similar.